# How to call `POST` RESTfull methods in Android?

Tags: java, android, rest, http, post

I have developed a web service in Java. Below is a method of it.

```
@Path("/setup")
public class SetupJSONService {

    @POST
    @Path("/insertSetup")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String insertSetup(SetupBean bean)
    {
        System.out.println("Printed");
        SetupInterface setupInterface = new SetupImpl();
        String insertSetup = setupInterface.insertSetup(bean);
        return insertSetup;
    }
}
```

Below is how I call this method using Java `Jersey` in my computer.

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/TestApp/rest/setup").path("/insertSetup");

SetupBean setupBean = new SetupBean();
setupBean.setIdPatient(1);
setupBean.setCircleType(1);

target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(Entity.entity(setupBean, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
```

However, Now this method should be called in Android as well, but I'm not sure how to do that. I know how to make `GET` calls in android like below.

```
public static String httpGet(String urlStr) throws IOException {
  URL url = new URL(urlStr);
  HttpURLConnection conn =
      (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

  if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    throw new IOException(conn.getResponseMessage());
  }

  // Buffer the result into a string
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  String line;
  while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
  }
  rd.close();

  conn.disconnect();
  return sb.toString();
}
```

But since my method is `POST` and since it accept a `Java Bean` and it does return a `String`, how can I handle this in Android?  Not interested using Jersey in android as it does have bad comments in Android environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android provides a way to do what you want, but this is not a productive way, i like to use retrofit 2 to power my development and to write a better code.

Here a example of retrofit 2 that can help you =) :

add to your dependencies in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'  
}
```

Create your retrofit builder that specifies a converter and a base url.

```
public static final String URL = "http://localhost:8080/TestApp/rest/";
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

Now create a Interface that will encapsulate your rest methods like below

```
public interface YourEndpoints {
    @POST("setup/insertSetup")
    Call<ResponseBody> insertSetup(@Body SetupBean setupBean);
}
```

Associate your endpoints interface with your retrofit instance.

```
YourEndpoints request = retrofit.create(YourEndpoints.class);

Call<ResponseBody> yourResult = request.insertSetup(YourSetupBeanObject);
    yourResult.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            //response.code()
            //your string response response.body().string()
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            //do what you have to do if it return a error
        }
    });
```

Ref to this links for more information:

http://square.github.io/retrofit/

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit

Comment: Thanks for the post. But why it cannot be done with normal inbuilt things? This way seems over completing.

Comment: You are welcome =), you can do it in a normal way ! I just want to point a more productive and easy to use way

Comment: Thanks. Any guidance for normal way? I think in Jersey also they internally convert the object to JSON before sending to server?

Comment: below answer with a normal way hehe

Comment: Thanks. In this answer what is 'YourEndPoint' please?

Comment: From https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit
 "With Retrofit 2, endpoints are defined inside of an interface using special retrofit annotations to encode details about the parameters and request method. In addition, the return value is always a parameterized Call<T> object such as Call<User>. If you do not need any type-specific response, you can specify return value as simply Call<ResponseBody>."

Comment: I believe this code is best, so I deeply tried this. Unfortunately didn't work, I have opened a new question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702150/android-issues-in-making-a-rest-call. what has gone wrong please?

Comment: hey bro, i will take a look =D

Answer (score 2):

that`s the code for the normal way you want

```
InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        try {
            //constants
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/TestApp/rest/");
           //Map your object to JSONObject and convert it to a json string
            String message = new JSONObject().toString();

            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setReadTimeout(1000);
            con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(message.getBytes().length);

            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");

            //open
            con.connect();

            //setup send
            os = new BufferedOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            os.write(message.getBytes());
            //clean up
            os.flush();

            //do somehting with response
            is = con.getInputStream();
            String contentAsString = readData(is,len);

            os.close();
            is.close();
            con.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e){
            try {
                os.close();
                is.close();
                con.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks. I think Gson can convert object to json

Comment: Yes, you can use Gson =)

Comment: Gson g = new Gson();
String json = g.toJson(YourObject);

Comment: Also as you can see, in server side my application is accepting java bean. So will this wotk?

Comment: Hi, will try both of them in couple of hours. It's now midnight here :D really appreciate your continouse support, will update you soon.