# Android: Issues in making a REST call

Tags: java, android, rest, http, retrofit

I have developed a REST API using Java, implementing `Jersey`. Now I am trying to connect my android application with it.

Below code is related to my REST API.

**PatientJSONService**

```
import bean.PatientBean;
import bean.UserBean;
import db.PatientImpl;
import db.PatientInterface;
import db.UserImpl;
import db.UserInterface;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/patient")
public class PatientJSONService 
{
    @POST
    @Path("/insertPatient")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String insertPatient(PatientBean bean)
    {
        System.out.println("Printed");
        PatientInterface patientInterface = new PatientImpl();
        String insertUser = patientInterface.insertPatient(bean);
        return insertUser;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/getAllPatients")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)       
    public List<PatientBean> getAllPatients()
    {
        PatientInterface patinetInterface=new PatientImpl();
        List<PatientBean> allPatients = patinetInterface.getAllPatients();

        return allPatients;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/getPatientById/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)       
    public PatientBean getPatientByFlareId(@PathParam("id")String flareId)
    {
        PatientInterface patinetInterface=new PatientImpl();
        PatientBean patientById = patinetInterface.getPatientById(id);
        return patientById;
    }

}
```

**PatientBean**

```
public class PatientBean {

    private int idPatient;
    private String id;

    public int getIdPatient() {
        return idPatient;
    }

    public void setIdPatient(int idPatient) {
        this.idPatient = idPatient;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return flareID;
    }

    public void setID(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

**PatientImpl**- (database class)

```
public class PatientImpl implements PatientInterface {

    @Override
    public String insertPatient(PatientBean patientBean) 
    {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO patient (id) values(?)";
        String result="";

        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        try
        {
            con = DBMaster.getInstance().getConnection();
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql.toLowerCase());

            ps.setString(1,patientBean.getID());

            ps.executeUpdate();
            con.commit();
            result = Common.SUCCESS;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            try
            {
                con.rollback();
                e.printStackTrace();
                result = Common.ROLLBACK;
            } 
            catch (SQLException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                result = Common.ROLLBACK_FAILED;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                ps.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println(result);
        return result;   
    }
}
```

Now you have a proper and a clear understanding of how my REST API looks like. Let's see how I programmed my Android application to access this API. In here I am actually using `retrofit 2` - http://square.github.io/retrofit/

**MainActivity**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import bean.Common;
import bean.PatientBean;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String URL = "http://x.x.x.x:8080/TestRest/rest/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        restCall();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void restCall()
    {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        YourEndpoints request = retrofit.create(YourEndpoints.class);

        PatientBean patientBean= new PatientBean ();
        patientBean.setId(SLKRT0065);

        Call<ResponseBody> yourResult = request.insertPatient(patientBean);
        yourResult.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                try {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "RESPONSE: " + response.body().string());
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                try {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "RESPONSE: "+"FAILED");
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

From the above class, have a look at the method `restCall()` where the REST call is happening.

**YourEndpoints**

```
public interface YourEndpoints {

    @POST("patient/insertPatient")
    Call<ResponseBody> insertPatient(@Body PatientBean patientBean);
}
```

I don't know what I have done wrong, but it simply didn't work. When I run this code, I get a `NULLPOINTERException` in here `Log.d("MainActivity", "RESPONSE: " + response.body().string());` which means the response is probably null/ If I remove that part the code runs fine, but I see nothing in the database.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: figure out how to verify/log that jersey got a request. if yes then validate that  the config of the request matches your path handlers in the jersey part of the code. ie jersey debugging connects from a client ( any client ) .. see if you can use curl  to GET or POST and to verify server side, then make sure that retrofit is composing same combo of http headers, parms,  and POST.body.

Comment: Did you debug if your endpoint are reached ?

Comment: in your YourEndpoints the Post annotation is like this? @POST("patient/insertPatient")

Comment: @LucasPaolillo: Sorry, forgot to add endpoint class. Updated the question with end points.

Comment: Thanks! like @RobertRowntree said, have you tested the end point with a rest client, like Advanced Rest Client? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

Comment: @LucasPaolillo: I actually called these using Jersey, so I know the methods are really working.

Comment: Do you use jackson to serialize and deserealize? if yes, do you annotate your bean with @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)? because in that case, the int idPatient property not passed.

Comment: @LucasPaolillo: hmm..Nothing like that, I have already posted everything. You can see my database class.

Comment: try to add to your bean server @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true), before class declaration

Comment: or you can send the idPatient just to test.

Comment: @LucasPaolillo: as parameter?

Comment: @LucasPaolillo: Just  wondering, is there any sample project with `retrofit 2` so I can check?

Comment: Yes, your android bean is equal the server bean right? you only send one property (id) to the server, try to add the idPatient too, patientBean.setIdPatient(5) for example, or instead of that, add to your class declaration the 
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class PatientBean {
....
}

Comment: ` try to add the idPatient too,` - Tried, no good.

Comment: Just wondering, see that part `yourResult.enqueue` in my code is not similar to your in yesterday. I was unable to add your code as it is as it generated errors there.

Comment: yes, now i saw, the second parameter as Retrofit is not allowed in your project?

Comment: @LucasPaolillo: If I added your code as it is, it is saying `anonymous class derived from callback must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method "onFailure(<Call T>,Throwable)" in callback`

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en

Comment: @LucasPaolillo: Hi, Thanks, using the above URL I managed to get the error by `response.errorBody()`. I was passing a Timestamp as well and there was an issue.

Comment: @LucasPaolillo: Totally solved this issue thank to you. The core issue is `Timestamp` and I have asked it here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724511/android-can-not-construct-instance-of-java-sql-timestamp-from-string-value Pls have a look

Comment: @LucasPaolillo: Yes, other issue also sorted out :) Now I'm facing a new issue, probably you know how to deal with it, will update you.

Comment: @LucasPaolillo: Done. Please have a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726649/android-restfull-api-called-from-retrofit-2-says-method-not-allowed