# Android: RESTfull API called from `retrofit 2` says `Method Not Allowed`

Tags: java, android, post, retrofit, retrofit2

I have developed a web service using Java and Jersey. Now I am trying to connect into it, call its methods and get data, using android.

Below is the related part of the web service.

```
import bean.PatientBean;
import bean.UserBean;
import db.PatientImpl;
import db.PatientInterface;
import db.UserImpl;
import db.UserInterface;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/patient")
public class PatientJSONService 
{

    @POST
    @Path("/getPatientById/{Id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)       
    public PatientBean getPatientById(@PathParam("Id")String Id)
    {
        PatientInterface patinetInterface=new PatientImpl();
        PatientBean patientById = patinetInterface.getPatientById(Id);
        return patientById;
    }

}
```

In my android application, I am using `Retrofit 2` to call the above REST method.

```
private void restCall()
    {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
                .create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        YourEndpoints request = retrofit.create(YourEndpoints.class);


        Call<PatientBean> yourResult = request.getPatientById("ERTA001");
        yourResult.enqueue(new Callback<PatientBean>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PatientBean> call, Response<PatientBean> response) {

                try {
//                    Log.d("MainActivity", "RESPONSE_A: " + response.body().toString());
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "RESPONSE: " + response.errorBody().string());
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PatientBean> call, Throwable t) {
                try {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "RESPONSE: "+"FAILED");
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
    }
```

Below is my `EndPoint` interface

```
public interface YourEndpoints {

    @POST("patient/getPatientById/{Id}")
    Call<PatientBean>getPatientById(@Body String Id);
}
```

However When I run the code, I get a HTML response from `Apache Tomcat Server`, which basically says `HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed`.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What happens if you manually make a request with Postman or something

Comment: Good question. But I really have no idea how to fire a postman call into this.

Comment: Your endpoint looks like a typical GET to me, why are you using a POST to retrieve a resource?

Comment: @TimCastelijns: Because I pass an ID... Anwyay, if this is GET, will it work?

Comment: Regardless if it will work or not, I suggest you read up on rest and http request methods, which one to use for what, etc. Just a tip

Comment: Solved your problem bro?

Comment: @LucasPaolillo: Of Course!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your ws endpoint to @GET, and then change your rest client to below code:

```
@GET("patient/getPatientById/{Id}")
Call<PatientBean>getPatientById(@Path("Id") String Id);
```

GET should be used to retrieve data from the server.
POST should be used to send data to the server.

Comment: i think the problem is that he sends as body what is expect as path param, so i suggest to change it to a get, do you saw any problem in that?

Comment: Could be. I was just looking for an explanation behind your answer

Comment: Another explanation would be that the @GET behavior is to just retrieve information, and do not do any changes in database, and looking for @PeakGen`s he does not do any changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GSON along with RetroFit, you should not need your own implementation within `getPatientById()`. And, yes you should be using a `GET` method.

```
public interface PatientService {

    @GET("patient/getPatientById/{Id}")
    Call<PatientBean> getPatientById(@Path("Id") String id);

}
```

If your `PatientBean` is setup correctly, you should be able to call the following to get a fully formed instance of the class:

```
PatientService service = retrofit.create(PatientService.class);
Call<PatientBean> call = service.getPatientById("ERTA001");

call.enqueue(new Callback<PatientBean> {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<PatientBean> call, Response<PatientBean> response) {
        mPatientBean = response.body();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<PatientBean> call, Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```